# Welcome page in JSF using pretty

Tags: java, jsf-2, prettyfaces

I'm using JSF 2.0.5, Tomcat 7.0.12 and  prettyfaces.

My web.xml file is:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My pretty file configuration:

```
<url-mapping>
    <pattern>/</pattern>
    <view-id>/jsp/index.jsf</view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

My index.jsp file is empty.

My question is, when i hit to http://www.foo.com/ he is eventually redirecting to 
http://www.foo.com/jsp/index.jsf and because of the pretty we redirecting to 
http://www.foo.com/ again. 
Can someone explain why he is hitting jsp/index.jsf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

Because I'm using pretty:

```
<url-mapping>
    <pattern>/</pattern>
    <view-id>/jsp/index.jsf</view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

So when I'm hitting http://www.foo.com/ the pretty translated the '/' to http://www.foo.com/jsp/index.jsf